# hostname -d returns nothing

Tags: bash, shell-script, command-line, command, hostname

I've RHEL 7.5 machine and when I hit `hostname -d` to get domain it returns nothing.

Also `hostname -f`, to return long host name returns name without domain.

Please help me to understand what changes I need to make `hostname -d` to return domain name.

Comment: This comment solved it for me: [https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-networking-3/hostname-d-returns-blank-how-to-set-domain-name-centos-6-3-a-4175443975/#post4862335](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-networking-3/hostname-d-returns-blank-how-to-set-domain-name-centos-6-3-a-4175443975/#post4862335) I had the order of the short and fqdn reversed.

Answer (score 1):

From hostname man page:

> It is not possible to set the FQDN or the DNS domain name with the
>   dnsdomainname command (see THE FQDN below).
>
> the Fqdn You can't change the FQDN (as returned by hostname --fqdn) or
>   the DNS domain name (as returned by dnsdomainname) with this command.
>   The FQDN of the system is the name that the resolver(3) returns for
>   the host name.
>
> Technically: The FQDN is the name gethostbyname(2) returns for the
>   host name returned by gethostname(2). The DNS domain name is the part
>   after the first dot.
>
> Therefore it depends on the configuration (usually in /etc/host.conf)
>   how you can change it. Usually (if the hosts file is parsed before DNS
>   or NIS) you can change it in /etc/hosts.
>
> You cannot change the FQDN with hostname or dnsdomainname.
>
> **The recommended method of setting the FQDN is to make the hostname be an alias for the fully qualified name using /etc/hosts, DNS, or
>   NIS. For example, if the hostname was "ursula", one might have a line
>   in /etc/hosts which reads
>   127.0.0.1            ursula.example.com ursula**